# How to make single-line EditText draw itself correctly when using a specific size

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I need to set the height and width of a EditText widget programmatically. I am using a RelativeLayout to do this, and it works fine as far as the size goes, but the actual widget paints itself incorrectly:

[image: Incorrect Drawing of EditText]

I would have expected it to paint like this (which it will if I set the height to ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT instead of my requested height - sometimes):
[image]

**Any ideas?**

*Please note that I can't switch to DIP:s (dpi independence is actually already handled by the engine that use this code). Also note that I haven't found any value of setTextSize() that fix the misbehaviour.*

*This is how I create my widget:*

```
  EditText et = new EditText(this);
  et.setFocusable(true);
  et.setSingleLine(true);
  et.setHint(label);
  et.setText(text);
  et.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,(h/3)+5);
  et.setId(cn); 
  rllp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(w,h);
  rllp.leftMargin = x;
  rllp.topMargin = y;
  layout.addView(et,rllp);
```

Comment: On a side note, this question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360236/edittext-height-issue, but that question use xml to define the layout, and I haven't been able to make it work using the proposed solution (changing the text size) my case

Answer (score 1):

try to change the last line of the posted code to this

```
layout.addView(et);
```

Comment: No, that did not change anything. Why do you believe that it would?

Comment: because you have already set the layoutparams to your edittext view

Comment: Thank you for that, it is redundant